# Hamcrest matcher fails to match Boolean type property

Tags: java, matcher, hamcrest

For class `A`;

```
public class A {
    Integer value;
    Integer rate;
    Boolean checked;
}
```

I am constructing a custom Matcher like this;

`Matchers.hasItems(allOf(
          hasProperty("value", equalTo(value)), 
          hasProperty("rate", equalTo(rate))))`

to check if a list of `A` contains the one with `"value" == value && "rate" == rate`

The problem I have is that, when I incorporate the `Boolean` type property `checked` as a constraint to this Matcher, it always fail with error msg `property "checked" is not readable`.

`Matchers.hasItems(allOf(
          hasProperty("value", equalTo(value)), 
          hasProperty("rate", equalTo(rate)),
          hasProperty("checked", equalTo(checked))))`

Is it somehow related to the getter methods of boolean type fields have `is` prefix rather than `get`, and may be Hamcrest fail to use `is` prefix for getter if it is not `boolean` but `Boolean` type field.

Also, I should add that I cannot modify the structure of class `A`, therefore I am stuck with `Boolean` type fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody responded to this question, but I have implemented my own `HasPropertyWithValue` class with this small modification in `propertyOn` method where is generates a `PropertyDescriptor` of the given bean and property name.

```
private Condition<PropertyDescriptor> propertyOn(T bean, Description mismatch) {
    PropertyDescriptor property = PropertyUtil.getPropertyDescriptor(propertyName, bean);
    if (property != null) {
        if (property.getReadMethod() == null && property.getPropertyType().equals(Boolean.class)) {
            String booleanGetter = "is" propertyName.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() propertyName.substring(1);
            for(Method method : bean.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
                if (method.getName().equals(booleanGetter)) {
                    try {
                        property.setReadMethod(method);
                    } catch (IntrospectionException e) {
                        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot set read method" e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        mismatch.appendText("No property \"" + propertyName + "\"");
        return notMatched();
    }

    return matched(property, mismatch);
}
```

Where after the creation of `PropertyDescriptor`, where is has null `readMethod`. I used Java Reflection to get the correct Boolean getter method that starts with `is` prefix, and add it to the property as `readMethod`. This has solved the issue, but in such an ugly way.

I also created a pull request for `Hamcrest` project in GitHub; https://github.com/hamcrest/JavaHamcrest/pull/136